# Resources files in XML editor in the Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

How can I open resources files (*.resx) in XML editor (XML Source) in the Visual Studio 2008, like it was in the Visual Studio 2005.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the file in the Solution Explorer → Open with ...

Then select "XML editor"